# Not able to cd into world-readable directory on NFS

Tags: permissions, nfs

There is a directory created by root, and I am not root user. But I am not able to do a cd into that directory in spite of having execute permission for others. Why so? Has the write permission on others has anything to do here?

```
>$ ls -l
drwxrwxrwx  8 root    root  4096 Aug 10  2010 abc/
>$ cd abc
-ksh: cd: abc: [Permission denied]
>$
```

It is a mount point. From the mount command, I see NFS.

Comment: `lsattr -d abc/` ?

Comment: lsattr: Permission denied While reading flags on abc

Comment: Is that a mount point with a mount on it?

Comment: Is there something like SELinux or AppArmor active?
What distro are you using?

Comment: @YoMismo : Yes, it is a mount point

Comment: What kind of system is being mounted? is it cifs? permission may depend on the mounted filesystem, not the directory permissions.

Comment: How do i know what kind of sysem is mounted? From the mount command, i see nfs

Comment: `ls -ld abc/.` ?

Comment: @wurtel : I get permission denied error

Comment: Then the mounted filesystem has a root directory that is not readable/excutable for your user ID.

Comment: To summarize, abc is a mountpoint where the original filesystem belonged to a different server on which I dont have access.  Hence, the file permissions being seen on abc is overridden by the permissions on the original file system.

Comment: If the problem is solved or gone, @Guru, please post an answer so that this question does not forever remain in the unanate.

Answer (score 1):

The directory `abc` is a mountpoint of a filesystem belonging to a different server, hence the permissions of the filesystem being shared overrides the permissions set on the mountpoint. The user(me) does not have the execute permission on the original filesystem and hence not able to get into the directory.